# How can I get site url from elgg database?

Tags: database, elgg

How can I get the elgg site url from database?
I don't know how to use elgg_get_site_url in javascript and replace it with http://localhost:8080/elgg-1.8.18/
this is my code:

```
var currentuser = "<?php echo $name; ?>";
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/elgg-1.8.18/mod/twostep/views/default/twostep/coder.php?user="+currentuser,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript it's `elgg.get_site_url()`